# How to assert that nested function called pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I've seen similar questions but none could help me. I simply have an aws lambda handler function, something like this:

```
def handler(event, context):
  key = "trouble"
  response = async_get(key)
  make_regulations(response)


def async_get(x):
  ...

def make_regulations(x):
  ...
```

I could mock **async_get** function like this in **test_lambda.py** (installed pytest-mock):

```
def test_handler(event: dict, context: dict, mocker):
    mocker.patch('app.async_get', return_value=mockResponseDict)
```

How can I assume that **make_regulations** function is also called with some variables (in this case mockResponseDict). I need something like:

```
def test_handler(event: dict, context: dict, mocker):
    mocker.patch('app.async_get', return_value=mockResponseDict)
    mocker.patch('app.make_regulations').assert_called()
```

Gone through documentation, none worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your last example looks right. What do you mean nothing worked for you? Are you seeing an error? You can use `assert_called_with` to check that the method was called with the correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `assert_called()` method on the `Mock` object:

```py
def test_handler(event: dict, context: dict, mocker):
    mocker.patch('app.async_get', return_value=mockResponseDict)
    mocker.patch('app.make_regulations')
    app.make_regulations.assert_called()
```

If you want to make sure it was called exactly once, use `assert_called_once()`:

```py
def test_handler(event: dict, context: dict, mocker):
    mocker.patch('app.async_get', return_value=mockResponseDict)
    mocker.patch('app.make_regulations')
    app.make_regulations.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: This case it says; AssertionError: Expected 'make_regulations' to have been called. But it has to be called, there's something wrong

Comment: @FatihErsoy If you use exactly this code, then it's not called. Did you call `handler`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to delete the reply. Your answer works